# Magento .htaccess file RewriteBase setting?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, redirect, internal-server-error

I've resolved a problem I got when I set up a staging environment for my existing live Magento store.  But I don't understand why it worked & why I didn't have the problem on my live site.

The was the error I was getting, whenever I tried to navigate off my sites staging homepage  I got a *500 Internal Server Error*.

In the error logs I got this:

```
[Tue Dec 17 01:12:52 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Dec 17 12:56:17 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://localhost.mysite.com/
```

With a little [research online](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/290044/), I solved it by changing the *.htaccess* file *RewriteBase* setting to `RewriteBase /`. On my live site this setting is commented out as `#RewriteBase /magento/`.

1. Why is this setting only needed in my staging environment?
2. Should it be on the live environment too or should it be avoided
   entirely?
3. I'm running the site locally on an Apache2 server on an Ubuntu
   machine, maybe it has something to do with my local server set up?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this setting only needed in my staging environment?

Probably because your staging environment is in a directory called `/magento/` inside your document root. When you have checks like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

and the base is wrong, the check to see if a file exists fails. The base is used to append to the beginning of relative URL-paths. So if your files are in `/magento/` then without the proper base, your checks will fail and your rules will loop indefinitely (or until the internal recursion limit is reached). On your production environment, the files are probably in your document root, so the base isn't completely necessary, since the rules are in the same directory as the files you are rewriting to.

As for the other 2 questions, can't answer without looking at all your rules and all of your setup.